# Windows installer on CD (executable bit)

Tags: wine

I am trying to install a Windows program with Wine, but it reports that it won't run because it's not executable. How in the world am I supposed to add an executable bit in the static medium of CD?

Comment: why don't you copy all fo the files and put them on a folder ? nd then try again

Comment: @Uri, I want to avoid doing that - I'm installing Ubuntu in school computers, and I won't be there to instruct everyone to copy and then use. I'm not even an employee but a LoCo member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run a windows executable, missing the execution permissions, prepending the executing program name, i.e. `wine`

```
wine /media/cdrom/app.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply re-author the disc. Copy the files over, change the needed permissions and then re-burn it.

Comment: ... That's even more troublesome than simply copying and then installing... Oh wait, so doing that, I won't need to copy it over and over again, you mean?

Comment: Straight ISO9660 or ISO9660+Joliet extensions do not support permissions. Olny ISO9660+Rock-Ridge extensions do.