# Graphical shortcut to command

Tags: programming, gui

In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43136/windows-installer-on-cd-executable-bit/43141#43141), this command is recommended:

```
wine /media/cdrom/app.exe
```

How can I make a simple graphical program to let me choose a variable for the file that was chosen in the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a new launcher that ran this:

```
wine "`zenity --file-selection`"
```

You might need to install Zenity first though:

```
sudo apt-get install zenity
```

Comment: Interesting idea. How exactly do I create a launcher again?

Comment: @Oxwivi Right click the desktop and select Create Launcher

Comment: Ah, I thought of Unity launchers... -.-'

Comment: What about the icon?

Comment: @Oxwivi What about it? Pick one you like most. I'm quite fond of [this one](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/tulliana-2-icons-by-umut-pulat/exec-wine-icon.html).

Comment: I created an application launcher, it doesn't work the the exact `wine`/`zenity` command you mention. Is it something else?