# File not marked as executable

Tags: permissions, executable

I'm trying to install a game that has a two-CD installation, and I get this error message:

> The file '/media/FREESPACE_1/Setup.exe' is not marked as executable. If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run. For more details, read about the executable bit.

Since it's on a CD, it is a read-only file and therefore I cannot change the permissions. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows installer on CD (executable bit)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43136/windows-installer-on-cd-executable-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try starting wine from terminal, giving it the name of your executable as an argument:

```
cd /media/FREESPACE_1
wine ./Setup.exe
```

Another option would be to somehow remount the cdrom passing different "mode" parameter to isofs driver - by default mode is 0400, which is "owner read-only", i.e. "r------". You need to change it at least to 0500, i.e. "r-x------". So something along the these lines technically should help - however, I couldn't make it work in my brief testing:

```
sudo mount /media/FREESPACE_1 -o remount,exec,ro,mode=500
```

Comment: To start a terminal in Ubuntu, go to Applications - Accessories - Terminal. If you're using the latest Ubuntu (with Unity), pressing Alt-F2 and typing "term" should show the icon

Comment: Pheew, lots of big programmer words in that second option, Sergey! :) You lost me at "isofs". I'm gonna try the first one.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but when I type that first line into the terminal, this is what I get: bash: cd: /media/freespace_1: No such file or directory

Comment: Ralf, I took the path from your question: "...file '/media/FREESPACE_1/Setup.exe' is not marked as...". Note that file and directory names in Unix are case-sensitive, so you should enter them exactly as they are, without changing case. So, if you enter "cd /media/FREESPACE_1" literally I'm pretty sure it should work

Comment: Not quite related, but may be helpful: auto-completion in terminal allows to avoid typing errors... start typing "cd /me", then press tab, then enter the first letter (F in your case), tab again - done. When it cannot auto-complete because your input in ambiguous, hitting tab twice lists the options.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Thanks Sergey, freebird, enzotib and LGB for your input.

Answer (score -1):

This is going to be a easy fix.

- open terminal

`gksudo nautilus` ( <<< be careful you will be using nautilus as root)

put in your password

go to your cdrom and right click  on setup.exe

goto permissions make the changes you need (check mark allow to run as executable ) close the property window and double click Setup.exe

Should work if wine and the game plays nice together.

Seeing that it didn't work you can also copy the cd to your hard drive and should be able to change  permissions of the files on your drive.

Comment: Thanks. Pardon my ignorance, but I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm running the Classic view, and I have no idea how to open the terminal.

Comment: Actually, I just found it. :)

Comment: Nope, still doesn't allow me to change the permission. :(

Comment: You cannot change permissions on a read-only media. Moreover, it is probably a ISO9660 filesystem that do not support executable bit (if it has not Rock Ridge extensions).

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you Technically as root you should be able to change any settings on any file. Ty enzotib I have never ran in to that issue before using nautilus as root has always done the trick for me. I guess i have just been lucky on that so far .

Comment: But even if you are root, you can't do modification on a filesystem which is read-only ... And altering permission means writing to the filesystem, which requires read/write fs, of course.